# for loop to check intersection through ArrayList of Rectangles

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, arraylist

This is my FIRST question on Stack so any advises how to do it better next time would be appreciated :) 
I've created a list consist of couple Rectangles. I'm trying to loop through this list to check the intersection between rectangle in a list and my dragged and released JLabbel on this rectangle. Here is my approach:

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    Component comp = (Component) e.getSource();
    Point locOnScreen = e.getLocationOnScreen();
    int x = locOnScreen.x - initialLocOnScreen.x + initialLoc.x;
    int y = locOnScreen.y - initialLocOnScreen.y + initialLoc.y;
    boundsSet(x, y, comp);//method to limit dragging space in contentPane 

    List<Rectangle> placeHolder = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();

    placeHolder.add(leftDesk);
    placeHolder.add(leftPainting);
    placeHolder.add(underBed);
    placeHolder.add(onBed);
    placeHolder.add(centerPainting);
    placeHolder.add(window);
    placeHolder.add(wardrobe);

    for (Rectangle holder : placeHolder) {
        if (holder.intersects(comp.getBounds())) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct place !");
            GameStatus.points += 10;
            GameStatus.nrOfItems--;
            if (GameStatus.points == 50)
                GameStatus.level++;

        } else
            comp.setLocation(initialLoc);
    }
}
```

I've set to Rectangles appropriate coordinates(checked hundreds times). The problem is that it detects only intersection with the first Rectangle in a List... If I will drag the label on another placed rectangle it will not detect it. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you just check it with one rectangle not all of them.

Comment: `"....so any advises how to do it better next time would be appreciated..."` -- please consider creating and posting a valid [mcve] or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Do you really need the `else` branch? I don't understand why it is here. Seems this changes position of the component after the first check.

Comment: I think your program does what you told it: when it intersects **not** the first rectangle in the list, the label will be put to its original location (`else`) so it can't never intersect anonther rectangle. Try to remove this `else` and look if it works.

Comment: That was that [IQV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/7434553/iqv) . What a stupid damn mistake... Thank You very much for Your help !

Comment: Tip, add @IQV (or whoever you're trying to reply to) instead of a link to their profile to notify them you've replied (the `@` is important)

Comment: Thanks @Frakcool for adivse. I'm new here so I need to gain experience with posting, editing and commenting on Stack, thus any advice is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the cycle as follows:

```
boolean found = false;

for (Rectangle holder : placeHolder) {
    if (holder.intersects(comp.getBounds())) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Correct place !");
        GameStatus.points += 10;
        GameStatus.nrOfItems--;
        if (GameStatus.points == 50)
            GameStatus.level++;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    comp.setLocation(initialLoc);
}
```

Comment: @IQV already solved my problem. I've just put an "else" statement in one bracket earlier than I should...
Thank You Guys for a quick response !